# Android Application Heap Size

Tags: android, heap-memory

how Android Determine that a specific amount of Heap should be allocated to an application?

For example if an application size is 13 mb and when Application is loaded on

MDPI device with ram 512 it allocate 20mb of Heap size for it

and if loaded on

`HDPI` device with `512 mb` ram it allocate `50mb` ram

and if loaded on

`HDPI` device with `1MB` ram still allocat `50mb` ram

for 
`XHDPI` Device with `1gb` Ram it allocate `68mb`

and for

`XXHDPI` device with `2GB` ram it allocate `134mb` of heap Size

My Questions are

- How Android Calculate and allocated size for the application ?
- Does this Allocation depends on RAM Size or Device type (like mdpi,hdpi etc) or dependent on both ?
- Does it Depends on OS ver ?
- Any Specific formula android OS Using to calculate and allocate memory to an application ?

Answer (score 2):

I would take a look at the [developer docs](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html).

> **Allocating and Reclaiming App Memory**
>
> Here are some facts about how Android allocates then reclaims memory
>   from your app:
>
> The Dalvik heap for each process is constrained to a single virtual
>   memory range. This defines the logical heap size, which can grow as it
>   needs to (but only up to a limit that the system defines for each
>   app). The logical size of the heap is not the same as the amount of
>   physical memory used by the heap. When inspecting your app's heap,
>   Android computes a value called the Proportional Set Size (PSS), which
>   accounts for both dirty and clean pages that are shared with other
>   processes—but only in an amount that's proportional to how many apps
>   share that RAM. This (PSS) total is what the system considers to be
>   your physical memory footprint. For more information about PSS, see
>   the Investigating Your RAM Usage guide. The Dalvik heap does not
>   compact the logical size of the heap, meaning that Android does not
>   defragment the heap to close up space. Android can only shrink the
>   logical heap size when there is unused space at the end of the heap.
>   But this doesn't mean the physical memory used by the heap can't
>   shrink. After garbage collection, Dalvik walks the heap and finds
>   unused pages, then returns those pages to the kernel using madvise.
>   So, paired allocations and deallocations of large chunks should result
>   in reclaiming all (or nearly all) the physical memory used. However,
>   reclaiming memory from small allocations can be much less efficient
>   because the page used for a small allocation may still be shared with
>   something else that has not yet been freed.
>
> **Restricting App Memory**
>
> To maintain a functional multi-tasking environment, Android sets a
>   hard limit on the heap size for each app. The exact heap size limit
>   varies between devices based on how much RAM the device has available
>   overall. If your app has reached the heap capacity and tries to
>   allocate more memory, it will receive an OutOfMemoryError.
>
> In some cases, you might want to query the system to determine exactly
>   how much heap space you have available on the current device—for
>   example, to determine how much data is safe to keep in a cache. You
>   can query the system for this figure by calling getMemoryClass(). This
>   returns an integer indicating the number of megabytes available for
>   your app's heap. This is discussed further below, under Check how much
>   memory you should use.

Just to extract the info you want:

1. The exact heap size limit varies between devices based on how much
   RAM the device has available overall.
2. You could delve into the source code to look at how heap memory is
   calculated, but I am not sure what you will gain from this.
3. The heap memory will probably vary on OS version as there will be
   many differences in service and OS resource usage that will affect
   how much RAM is available to a device after this has been taken from
   the gross total RAM.

If you are really looking for in depth info on memory heap, i would use the memory debugging tools [detailed here](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html).

Answer (score 1):

It's not really calculated. Heap memory is allocated from the underlying operating system as needed, up to a VM-specific limit. What you see is the allocated heap size.

Why it's different for different devices is mainly because higher resolution bitmaps require more memory.

Comment: if you call maxmemory() for run time you will get an upper limit that means it comes from some calculation,and it is pretty obvious that without any calculation it wont't give any space so i disaggree with you that `it's not really calculated`

Comment: `Runtime.maxMemory()` returns the VM-specific limit. It's a configuration setting set by the device manufacturer.